# How to replace non-ASCII quotes with ASCII quotes in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, unicode

I am trying to replace all occurrences of non-ASCII quotes (like `‘`, `’`, `“` and `”`) in a string with an ASCII single quote (`'`), because when I write to a file, they come out like this: `Petersonâ€™s`, instead of `Peterson's`. I tried using the following regular expression:

```
paragraph.replace(/"/g, "'");
```

but this did not work. How can I specify that I want to replace all occurrences of those non-ASCII characters in my regular expression?

Comment: Instead of replacing apostrophes, you really should fix your file encoding.

Comment: Could you give me some pointers on how to do that? For writing the file, I use fs.createWriteStream(csvFile, {encoding: 'utf8'}), and for reading I use fs.readFile(htmlFile, 'utf8', function (error, htmlData). I don't understand why these characters get replaced, since I read and write as a utf-8 file.

Comment: Best ask that as a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with your complete code, and some example input.

Answer (score 2):

Specify all those characters in a character class, and don't forget to get the value returned by `replace` (strings in Javascript are immutable):

```
paragraph = paragraph.replace(/["“‘”]/g, "'");
```